# Why is making a Get request functioning in Xampp but not working when I deploy to Server?

Tags: php, xampp

My application tries to resemble an MVC architectural pattern. In Xampp the application works as it should. On the server it is deployed on, it does not work. I have narrowed down the problem, and it seems to happen every time I make a GET request from a form or if I click on a link that redirects me to another part of the site.

In Xampp the URL http://localhost/dealer_login/Quote/quoteDetails?quote_number=532468
On the hosted server  the URL is
http://webdev.fakesite.com/dealer_login-prod/public/index.php?url=Quote/reviewQuotesOrders

I have to add the public/index.php part. My .htaccess files don't seem to be working on the server.

Initially I didn't think it was a big deal, but when it comes to making "GET" request the URL is interpreted differently.

For example in Xampp
http://localhost/dealer_login/Quote/quoteDetails?quote_number=532468 works fine.

It checks for a Quote class and then calls the quoteDetails method. Everything after the question mark is not considered part of the method in the Quote class.

Array ( [0] => Quote [1] => quoteDetails )

On the server quoteDetails?quote_number=532442 is being considered as part of a method in a class. It does not find it so I then get redirected to my index page.

Array ( [0] => Quote [1] quoteDetails?quote_number=532442 )

Why is this happening ?

Here is my core class which basically instantiates each class and calls its method based on whatever is in the URL.

```
<?php
/*
   * App Core Class
   * Creates URL & loads core controller
   * URL FORMAT - /controller/method/params
   */
class Core
{
  protected $currentController = 'Pages';
  protected $currentMethod = 'index';
  protected $params = [];

  public function __construct()
  {

    $url = $this->getUrl();

    // Look in controllers for first value
    if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]) . '.php')) {
      // If exists, set as controller
      $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
      // Unset 0 Index
      unset($url[0]);
    }

    // Require the controller
    require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';

    // // Instantiate controller class
    $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

    if (isset($url[1])) {
      if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
        $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
        unset($url[1]);
      }
    }
    print_r($url);
    //If there is anything left in our Url after unsettting the current method and current controller then mass those values 
    //via the call_user_func_array. 
    //$this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

    call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
  }

  public function getUrl()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
      $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
      $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
      $url = explode('/', $url);
      return $url;
    } else {
      $url[0] = 'Pages';
      return $url;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your server use Apache? Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: @brombeer I ran php info to see I could find it enabled there. I know its an Apache thing , but I was wondering if I could find any info on that document. In my /etc/apache2/ directory, the only thing that exists is a conf-available directory. I am going to assume it is not enabled. Would that explain that behavior ?

Comment: The server uses nginx without mod_rewrite. I have just found out that .htaccess files do not work on nginx.